# How do I get my question noticed?

Tags: discussion, questions, unanswered-questions

I haven't been able to find anything related to this, so far. I asked a question on SO with little to say. What I mean is that I pushed a bunch of buttons and nothing happened. It's as simple as that. No error messages or anything. None of the research helped me, either.

There was nothing to show and nothing to say. Yet, I've found that people like questions with lots of details in about a couple of hundred words. There were no comments or anything for several days, so I offered a 50 rep bounty for it. Again, nothing.

My IDE is not working, so I basically can't do any programming. I need some help fast. The problem is that no one wants to help me because I'm not providing any details, even though there are none.

How do I provide details when there are none? How do I get my question answered before I forget how to write C++ code? I have seen this, but I already offered a bounty on it.

Comment: People respond to interesting questions and ones they think they can answer. Your question about the IDE being broken doesn't really give anyone anything to go off of. Your question has been viewed plenty of times but since it boils down to "nothing works and I don't know why", we can't really know why either.

Comment: @MikeC Do you have any idea of where I can go from here? I've run into a dead end and my brain is fried.

Comment: I've already commented on your question.

Comment: post a screenshot, so maybe someone can help you

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife Of what?

Comment: Why not just use another editor? There's only so much that can be done with no details whatsoever.

Comment: @Laurel I tried Eclipse, but it won't download properly. I've tried Qt, but it's confusing me. I even tried Kdevelop, but it isn't working properly. I tried MonoDevelop, but I need to be able to make a GUI.

Comment: When Laurel was talking about editor, he really meant a *editor*, not an IDE. Try something simpler. Notepad++ and emacs are popular editors which are extensible, and since you need to be able to write to be able to do something useful, simpler seems to be the faster solution here.

Comment: There's more than 4 compilers/IDEs for C++ you know. A quick search gets you bunches of forums like [this one](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/48102/) that list out dozens more.

Comment: @Braiam You mean "she". There's still time to edit your comment!

Comment: @Braiam I did you use a text editor for several weeks, but I didn't really like it. Notepad++ doesn't work on Linux, and neither does emacs. I'll look into again, though.

Comment: @Laurel lol. Looks like none of those options really apply to me since I'm using Linux. I'll look for more, though. Thanks.

Comment: "emacs not working on Linux"... you will not go far on any site with such statement - unless you want to really start flame war :) ... Not appropriate for any SE sites so.

Comment: The fact that you are using Linux (but which strain?) should have been mentioned in your original SO question. But there are [plenty specifically for Linux too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109/c-ide-for-linux)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What I said was an answer to a previous comment.

Comment: @Laurel I didn't think that was important since the same problem resides on Windows and Linux.

Comment: Are you sure that your problems stems from the IDE/editor but something else, like low free space, read only/permissions issues, dependency problems, etc. BTW, emacs [works in Linux, Windows and OSX.](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html)

Comment: @Braiam What do you mean by dependency problems?

Comment: Some software requires certain libraries to be in certain versions, or certain libraries not to be present, or to be present, or whatever. If you install the IDE with the package manager (apt, yum, emerge, etc.) it shouldn't be a problem, but for me it seems that you are trying to manually install them, which tend to cause problems if you aren't familiar with them.

Comment: @Braiam The more I read about these things, the more I just want to jump in bed and pull the covers over my head:)

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone mentioned this, but bounty would greatly increase your chance of getting an answer. But beware as it's reduces your reputation.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas Thanks for the tip, but I assigned +50 to it quite a while ago. That's why I'm worried.

Comment: Hmm... Well, I don't know what else to suggest... Maybe bump question, I see people do it from time to time. I have run out of ideas.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas That's what I was I hoping _not_ to read:) What do you mean by"bump".

Comment: Bumping question means sending back to newest quesyions list (by activity). People might notice and answer.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas So that's why editing a question gets more responses?

Comment: Most likely because editing questions it is being sent back to the top.

Answer (score 7):

> I need *some help fast*. The problem is that no one wants to help me because I'm *not providing any details*, even though there are none."

SO is simply not a place to look for help of this kind. You need personal help of someone familiar with platform/tools you are using. Asking on support forum for tool/IDE/library or paid support (tool provider's or generic) may be an option.

There is nothing you can do to make such question on-topic or even answerable on SO.

Note: it is generally assumed that Linux users are able to debug wide range of configuration issues than users of closed platforms like Apple's operating systems or Microsoft Windows. Posting no configuration on Linux specific SE site will likely get only negative attention.

Comment: @VeniVidiVici there are companies providing paid support for different platforms in general, sometimes owner of libraries/tools have such an option - search and pick. Again SO/Meta.SO is not place to find recommendation on that.

Comment: I agree, if you're facing a problem with a certain software package, the best place for advice is a specific forum, where this package use is discussed.